# Getting around shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier's paradox

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm an iOS newbie trying to get this right...

I'm trying to use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` in order to add some validation before allowing the segue to go through.

I'm using an Exit segue through a Bar Button, whose method (`unwindToChecklist`) is written in the destination view controller (called `ChecklistViewController`). I'm assuming that's why it isn't working, because the source view controller (`AddItemViewController`) has no segue called unwindToList, even though it's listed under `AddItemViewController`'s list of elements on the left sidebar in the Storyboard.

I've already ensured that the segue's identifier is named `unwindToChecklist` in the attributes inspector.

My code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Checking...");

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"unwindToChecklist"]) {
        if (![self.txtItemTitle.text  isEqualToString: @""]) {
            return NO;
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item Name Empty"
                                                        message:@"Please fill in the title name text field."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Screenshots of 1) the scene sidebar & 2) attributes inspector:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? What result is the code you posted giving you? Your assumption is wrong, you do have a segue in the AddItemViewController according to what you've posted.

Comment: @rdelmar I do, but the method `unwindToChecklist` is in a different view controller, and so the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method won't work on it.

Comment: In which controller do you have the shouldPerformSegue? It should be in the source view controller, AddItemViewController. It shouldn't matter what controller has the unwindToChecklist method, it's the controller that initiates the segue that decides whether it should be executed or not.